# Data in TreeView.ItemTemplate HierarchicalDataTemplate gets erased when switching the Selected TreeItem

Tags: wpf, mvvm, treeview, itemtemplate

I have the following code:

`Template.XAML`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="Header">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ContentControl  Foreground="Red" 
                       FontFamily="Segoe UI" 
                       Margin="0,0,0,20" 
                        Content="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=HeaderedContentControl}}" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel}">
    <HeaderedContentControl  xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                   Tag="{Binding Header}"
                   Background="SteelBlue"
                   BorderBrush="DarkSlateBlue">
    </HeaderedContentControl>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel2}">
    <HeaderedContentControl  xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                   Tag="{Binding Header}"
                   Background="SteelBlue"
                   BorderBrush="DarkSlateBlue">
    </HeaderedContentControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

`Windows.XAML:`

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:WindowsVM x:Name="viewModel"/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Templates.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TreeView SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding AllContents}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding Header}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

`Windows.XAML.cs`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        viewModel.SelectedItem = (ViewModel)e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

`ViewModel.cs`

```
public class WindowsVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public WindowsVM()
    {
        AllContents = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>();
        AllContents.Add(new ViewModel("Item 1"));
        AllContents.Add(new ViewModel2("Item 2")); //using ViewModel("Item 2") will show the Header as it should
        SelectedItem = AllContents.First();
    }

    private ViewModel _selectedItem;
    public ViewModel SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedItem)));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ViewModel> _allContents;
    public ObservableCollection<ViewModel> AllContents
    {
        get { return _allContents; }
        set
        {
            _allContents = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(AllContents)));
        }
    }
}

public  class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _header;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Header
    {
        get { return _header; }
        set
        {
            _header = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Header)));
        }
    }

    public ViewModel(string header)
    {
        Header = header;
    }
}


public class ViewModel2 : ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel2(string header) : base(header)
    {
    }
}
```

If you run the application, the "Item 1" will be shown as the header of the selected item, as it should.

If you click on the second tree node, I would expect "Item 2" shown as the header of the selected item, but it is not.

Here comes the interesting part, if for "Item 2", it is of the type `ViewModel` instead of `ViewModel2`, then the "Item 2" header will be shown. How come this is happening? Is this a WPF `treeview` bug?

I would also welcome workaround, in the spirit of MVVM model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind the `Header` property of the `HeaderedContentControl` to your `Header` source property and then define a `HeaderTemplate` in the `HeaderedContentControl` style.

If you implement `Templates.xaml` like this, your example works as expected:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Foreground="Red" 
                       FontFamily="Segoe UI" 
                       Margin="0,0,0,20" 
                       Content="{Binding}" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel}">
    <HeaderedContentControl Header="{Binding Header}"
                   Background="SteelBlue"
                   BorderBrush="DarkSlateBlue">
    </HeaderedContentControl>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel2}">
    <HeaderedContentControl Header="{Binding Header}"
                   Background="SteelBlue"
                   BorderBrush="DarkSlateBlue">
    </HeaderedContentControl>
</DataTemplate>
```